# How to handle missing data in a csv file without using numpy/pandas?

Tags: python, parsing, csv, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to extract data from a csv file I have that contains some missing data

```
Num,Sym,Element,Group,Weight,Density,Melting,Boiling,Heat,Eneg,Radius,Oxidation
1,H,Hydrogen,1,1.008,0.00008988,14.01,20.28,14.304,2.2,53,"[1,-1]"
2,He,Helium,18,4.002602,0.0001785,0.956,4.22,5.193,No_Data,31,[0]
etc
```

In this case the missing value is the electronegativity of Helium, a noble gas.  I also want to parse this data all at once (ie when I read it in) and cast it to the appropriate data type so I can perform calculations as needed, using this function

```
import csv

def read_periodic_table(): 
    per_table = {}
    with open("element_list.csv", "r") as f:
        my_reader = csv.reader(f)
        my_reader.next() # Just skipping the header
        try:
            while True:
                tl = my_reader.next()
                per_table[tl[1]] =(int(tl[0]), tl[2], int(tl[3]), float(tl[4]),
                                   float(tl[5]), float(tl[6]), float(tl[7]),
                                   float(tl[8]), float(tl[9]), float(tl[10]),
                                   list(tl[11]))

        except StopIteration:
            return
```

This works fine, except when there are places where there is no data (as above) and I get a `TypeError`.  I get why there is an error - you can't really cast `"No_Data"` to a floating point number.

I've read these questions

- [Definitive way to parse alphanumeric CSVs in Python with scipy/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981383/definitive-way-to-parse-alphanumeric-csvs-in-python-with-scipy-numpy?rq=1)
- [How do you deal with missing data using numpy/scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377130/how-do-you-deal-with-missing-data-using-numpy-scipy)

which could probably answer my question, except I'd like to avoid using extra libraries for just one function.

The only way that I can think of handling this is some `try/except` blocks... a lot of them

Something like this

```
num = tl[0]
name = tl[2]
group = tl[3]
try:
    weight = float(tl[4])
except TypeError:
    weight = "No_Data"
finally:
    try:
        density = float(tl[5])
    except TypeError:
        density = "No_Data"
    finally:
        try:
            ...
```

Which, for what I hope are obvious reasons, I'd rather avoid.  Is there a way using only the standard library to accomplish this?  If the answer is - "No, not very easily/well" then that's fine, I'll just use numpy/pandas.  I'd just like to avoid that if possible.  Alternately, if there is a fantastic answer with numpy/pandas and a compelling reason why using an extra library wouldn't be bad I'd take that too.

The reason I don't want to use a third party library is that several people, including myself, will be working on this and then quite a few people will be using it afterwards.  I'd rather not make them all install another library to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I was absolutely determined to not use `pandas`, I'd do something like this:

- Specify the type for each column
- Write a quick conversion function to try out each conversion
- Use a list comp/generator expression to call the conversion function on each cell

```
def convert_type(cell, typ):
    try:
        return typ(cell)
    except TypeError:
        return "No_Data"

# These lines go below 'tl = my_reader.next()' in your code
col_types = [int, str, int, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, list]
new_row = tuple(convert_type(cell, typ) for cell, typ in zip(tl, col_types))
per_table[tl[1]] = new_row
```

That said, if I was doing this myself, I would definitely use `pandas`. A distribution like Anaconda is a good option for getting Python set up quickly with lots of useful libraries like `pandas` already included.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that with your last column, you'd have to replace `list` with a custom function that converts the string representation of the list into an actual python list, the `list()` call won't do it so you'll just get `"No_Data" for all rows.

Comment: Won't this also pass in the `Sym` value? I intended to exclude that because I'm using it as the dict key

Comment: Yes, sorry, it will pass in the `Sym`/`tl[1]` value. You could slice up `new_row` before putting it in the table or find some other way of mapping between column positions and conversion functions like a dict, the main idea I was trying to get across was having some kind of mapping that identifies the type of each column.

Answer (score -2):

i think the best way to import text data, with missing values, to python is numpy's [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) function. it is very easy to use. in my case missing values are indicated by '?', you should use empty string ''.

```
 train = np.genfromtxt(path + 'cleveland.data', float, delimiter=',',missing_values='?',filling_values=np.nan)
```

Comment: Like I said, I'm trying to avoid using numpy

Comment: sorry, i was reading multiple questions about missing values in python. i didn't read your question carefully.